# Store view state in URL using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, url, angularjs, state, angular-routing

What's the general (if there is any) consensus on storing view states as part of the URL in `Angularjs` and how would I go about doing it? I have a fairly complex view/route with many filters to set, tabs, etc which result in a view state.

I see the advantage for storing the state of all these view components as part of the URL in an easier navigation within the application (navigating `back` would restore the previous view with all selections made without loading the state from the server, which would be an alternative). Another advantage is that the view state becomes bookmarkable.

Is there a pattern that I can use for guidance? Has anyone done this before and can share some experiences? Should I stay away from storing view states in the URL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the required data can be seriaslized into an { `key`, `value` }, then you can use [`$location.search()`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$location#methods_search) to save and retrieve this information in your controllers:

```js
app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope, $location, $routeParams) {
    // Load State
    var savedState = $location.search();
    allProperties.forEach(function (k) {
        if (typeof savedState[k] !== 'undefined') {
            $scope.model[k] = savedState[k];
        } else {
            $scope.model[k] = defaultValues[k];
        }
    });

    // Save the parameters
    $scope.createUrlWithCurrentState = function() {
         allProperties.forEach(function (k) {
             $location.search(k, $scope.model[k]);
         });
    });
})
```

Now you can call `createUrlWithCurrentState` with `ng-change` of each `input` element which has an `ng-model` and the state will be saved with each change, or you can call this function in `ng-click` on `Create a link to this page` button.

You will have to take care to keep `allProperties` and `defaultValues` updated to save all the required parameters, though.

---

As to whether this *should* be done or not, the answer depends on your use case. If you have to allow sharing of links, then there are very few alternatives to keeping state in URL.

However, some state may not be easy to serialize or the data may [just be too long to save in the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request).

If you want to preserve the retrieve information only for the current session or browser, you can look at [the `$cookieStore`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies.$cookieStore) or [the DOM Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage).

Comment: Thanks for the `location.search()` pointer and mentioning the URL length restrictions. It would be nice if one could encode/compress the state (the key-value pairs) somehow, so the length was be bounded...

Comment: That depends on your application and the data you want to save. If push comes to shove, one _can_ get creative and start saving it in `base64` or even `gzip` it on the fly in the app, but I don't think it will come to that easily. I would recommending crossing that bridge when you come to it.

Comment: ...or some other compression (`base64` and `gzip` will most likely generate illegal URL characters). But I'll follow your recommendation and see how far I get without resorting to anything too difficult.